# Microsoft Teams Channel is getting hidden when created using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, microsoft-teams, channel, hidden

I am having a postman request where I am Creating a team with multiple channels, installed apps, and pinned tabs using delegated permissions.

I am referring below Microsoft API document - see Example 3
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http][text]

When channels are getting created under teams. It's getting hidden and I have to manually unhide it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoxhz.png)Is there any way through Graph API that we should unhide it.

Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Ker.png)

I tried by using below two properties.

"isFavoriteByDefault": true
"membershipType": "standard"

but nothing worked and also tried creating with beta version.

Comment: This is a known issue. Channel property isFavoriteByDefault is not being applied. Setting isFavoriteByDefault to true while creating a team is not being applied. Favorite channel should be visible directly under General channel. But these are being shown within hidden channels. It is being tracked here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/417.